NestJS deployment on vercel having issue with swagger
I was following these two tutorials

https://www.technog.com.br/blog/tips-and-tricks/how-to-deploy-a-nestjs-app-for-free-on-vercel/
https://dev.to/leduc1901/how-to-deploy-your-nestjs-apps-on-vercel-3nh9

to make deployments to Vercel but instead of using the vercel cli to deploy I used the UI in vercel instead but after deployment I kept on seeing this error in deployment log
src/common/configs/swagger.ts(10,7): error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof expressBasicAuth' has no call signatures.

That error is actually calling my swagger setup which looks like
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import * as basicAuth from 'express-basic-auth';

const SwaggerSetup = (app) => {
  const SWAGGER_ENVS = ['local', 'dev', 'staging'];

  if (SWAGGER_ENVS.includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
    app.use(
      ['/api', '/api-json'],
      basicAuth({
        challenge: true,
        users: {
          [process.env.SWAGGER_USER]: process.env.SWAGGER_PASSWORD,
        },
      }),
    );

    const options = new DocumentBuilder()
      .setTitle('Title')
      .setDescription('Description')
      .setVersion('1.0')
      .build();

    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);

    SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document, {
      swaggerOptions: {
        docExpansion: 'none',
      },
    });
  }
};

export default SwaggerSetup;

I thought it might be TS version issue and so, which I updated and changed.  Things are still running fine locally and swagger working fine locally too.
Not too sure where else I can try to look into to solve this issue.
Thanks you for in advance for any suggestions.
